# Android Mysql - too many results

Tags: php, mysql

I've been struggling with this problem for a couple of days and can't make any progress... 
I'm trying to get just ONE result from my database but on contrary I'm getting the whole table : (

php:

```
{
   $connect = @mysqli_connect ($host, $username, $pass, $dbname)
   OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL');

   $table = $_REQUEST['table'];
   $key = $_REQUEST['id'];
   $key_value = $_REQUEST['id_value'];

   $q = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." where ".$key."='".$key_value."'";
   $r = @mysqli_query ($connect, $q);

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
      $output[]=$row;
   print(json_encode($output));
}
```

I think there's no need to show you my android code for that since the data is received well (also updating tables works fine) ... all i want is to get that ONE result from my DB.

When simply navigating to this file on the browser there's no problem obviously...
Thanks in advance, cheers

Comment: Not an answer but you shouldn't be running any old values that are passed in from a request in cause someone nasty passes in something malicious.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something like `where 1 = 1` and that is always true. You are not naming your column. You are replacing that with a number.

try this (unverified):

```
"SELECT * FROM ".$table." where id='".$id."'";
```

Comment: And what will this do?  How is it different from what he's already doing?

Comment: @juergend is correct, this is different, the original doesnt have the column id=$id, it has the variable twice, so it'll be something like: select * from table where 5=5;

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - didn't read the asker's code carefully enough.  However this still doesn't help with the issue in the question.

Comment: I made mistake above, of course program goes as: SELECT * FROM table where key='key_value' however even with the keyword LIMIT 1 the array still comes back with all the table content .. even though I loop throug the results how come other results are picked up ? the ID in the database is uniqe for evry row...

Comment: @user1167309 could you output the value of $q after it's set, just to make sure it's correct, this sounds like an odd problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get just the first row of the results, then you have two options:

1. include `LIMIT` in your query (preferred solution)

   SELECT * FROM ".$table." where ".$id."='".$id."' LIMIT 1"
2. don't loop to get all the data, simply read the first row and return it.

Comment: Reading the first row and returning it is bad, since you still relatively have a lot of overhead on the database side.

Comment: I totally agree - this is why I stated that (1) is the preferred solution.  In reality, there may be some valid case where you need to query the whole table and then return only the first row: usually when you need to do something with the rest of the data but don't need to display it.   I don't know the logic of his program, so suggested this as an option.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting your condition to `where ".$id."='".$id."'";`, so, if you pass id=1, that will mean: `WHERE 1=1`, and that is always **true**. that's why it's returning all the records.

Comment: I made mistake above, of course program goes as: SELECT * FROM table where key='key_value' however even with the keyword LIMIT 1 the array still comes back with all the table content .. even though I loop throug the results how come other results are picked up ? the ID in the database is uniqe for evry row...

Comment: can you do `echo $q` to see how your query looks after being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $table = $_REQUEST['table'];
   $key = $_REQUEST['id'];
   $key_value = $_REQUEST['id_value'];

   $q = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." where ".$id."='".$id."'";
```

You're assigning $key and $key_value but then using $id.

Comment: I made mistake above, of course program goes as: SELECT * FROM table where key='key_value'  however even with the keyword LIMIT 1 the array still comes back with all the table content .. even though I loop throug the results how come other results are picked up ? the ID in the database is uniqe for evry row...